# Reading C unformatted binary file using fortran 90

Tags: c, file-io, fortran, binaryfiles, fortran90

I just received a binary unformatted file for C, IEEE-float, and I'd like to open it using Fortran 90. It seems the file is originally one matrix 513 by 251, but could be the case that there are more things inside, like the size of the matrix, the dimensions, etc.  Is it possible? How do I read everything into a variable?

Here is the code example of my first try.!

```
program ReadDataIn
  real               :: DataIn
  character(len=90)    :: FileName= Path/and/file_name/of/the/C_binaryfile

  open (99, file = trim(FileName), iostat=ios, form = 'unformatted', ACCESS='stream')
  read(99) DataIn
  close(99)
  print*, DataIn
endprogram ReadDataIn
```

After compiling and running the code, I got just one number at the `print*, DataIn`.

For sure there are more then one number stored.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. (Did not allow to post as an answer, but nothing more can be said for such a question.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer .. I just modified a bit the question, to be more specific.!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Fortran read bytes directly from a binary file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569644/can-fortran-read-bytes-directly-from-a-binary-file)

Comment: The first glaring issue is that you are reading the data into a scalar variable.  If you want an array of data, you need to declare an array to read the data into.

Comment: @Jonathan Dursi thanks for the post. I tried what is written on the  link you wrote. However, for me it produced the same output as my code ... In any case, I have learned new thinks... Thanks!

Comment: Hey @casey, I thought about this, but how to define one array in advance if I do not know the size of the "array" is stored on the binary file I am trying to read in ... A bit confusing this apparent simple problem.!Thanks ..

Comment: Your question states the array size -- why can't you declare that size in your Fortran program? Or is the problem more general, that you are going to be given many files, of various lengths?  You could read a one real at a time to determine its length, but unless the file contains the dimensions of a 2D array, I don't see how you can recover that information.

Comment: I think the basic problem here is that you don't know what's in the file ("_could be the case that there are more things inside, like the size of the matrix, the dimensions_"), and no, you can't automatically read a raw binary file if you don't know what data is in there and in what format - not in Fortran, not in C, not in anything.  Your best bet is to use `od` or similar tools to inspect the file, infer the contents, and write read commands accordingly.

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for all answers. I ended up with the solution. It is dirty, but it works at the end. It is a trying/error code. What  I did: I set DataIn as an allocatable variable and tried  different dimensions inside a loop. For each try I read the input file. When the code stopped with an error, I knew the correct dimension (one loop before). I started again with the correct dimension, and it worked ...

Answer (score 1):

if just the matrix was written, C would just write the  513 by 251 numbers.  Fortran by default normally writes extra information, so instead open the file with `access="stream"`.  And of course `form="unformatted"`.  The other difference is that C is row-major and Fortran column-major, so with Fortran read in a 251 x 513 matrix.  If you need it to be 513 by 251, transpose it.  There could be more things in the file if the C program was written to write more ... in that case you need to know what the C programmer wrote, or reverse engineer, e.g., by using a hex-editor.

Comment: Thanks ... I tried: open (99, file = trim(FileName), iostat=ios, form = 'unformatted', ACCESS='stream')  and then read(99) DataIn. But when I print*, DataIn   Just one number appears on the monitor. What is going on?

Comment: @Quim you would be better served to edit your sample code into your question to show what you've tried and what happens when you run it.  It is impossible to address your comments because we don't have any idea what DataIn is, we'll need to see how that variable is declared.

Comment: @Quim In your code `Datain` is declared `real`, it is one number. If you read one number, you get one number. If your one number multiple times, you will get several numbers in sequence.

Comment: Hi @Vladimir, this is what I did to solve the problem ... Thanks.!