# How to write .bin file in R and open it in Fortran

Tags: r, fortran, binaryfiles

I have a Fortran model that I would like to force with data coming from a model developed in R, but I have trouble transferring the data between the two environments. I was thinking about using a .bin file.

What I am doing in  R is using `writeBin` to store a multi-dim array in a .bin file:

```
a = seq(1,150,1)
my.array <- array(a, dim=c(10,5,3)) 

zz <- file("test.bin", "wb")
writeBin (as.vector(my.array),zz)
close(zz)
```

I can read the .bin file in R without problem again...

```
zz <- file("test.bin", "rb")
a1 = readBin(zz,"numeric", n=150)
close(zz)

my.array1 <- array(a1, dim=c(10,5,3)) 
my.array1
```

However when I try to open it in Fortran using the following code, the format is not recognized correctly.

```
PROGRAM playground
implicit none

! Type declarations
real, dimension (5,10,3) ::  a

! read binary
open(unit = 10, status='old',file='test.bin', form='formatted', action='read')  
read(10,"(f11.3)") a 

print*,a

END PROGRAM playground
PROGRAM playground
```

I assume I am using the wrong format in the `read` command, but not sure where I am going wrong as Fortran is new to me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to open the file as `form='formatted'`.

Formatted means human readable, that is, a text file.

You definitely need `form='unformatted'`. But the default would be `access='sequential'` which is not good for you, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11570277/721644

You should use `access='stream'` (or more complicated `access='direct'`).

The code from the linked answer can be adapted very easily to your problem. Just declare the array as:

```
real(rp), dimension (5,10,3) ::  a
```

and you must test which value of `rp` is the right one. I think the default real you tried is wrong and you need

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

integer, parameter :: rp = c_double
```

to use the C double precision real.

Then just

```
open(unit = 10, status='old',file='test.bin', form='unformatted', &
     access='stream', action='read')  
read(10) a
```