# write array to .bin file in R

Tags: arrays, r, binaryfiles

Hei, I am trying to write a 3 dimensional array in R to a .bin file to later call it from FORTRAN.

I use the following approach:

```
my.array <- array(1:36, dim=c(3,4,3)) 

zz <- file("new.bin", "wb")
writeBin (my.array,zz, size = 8 )
close(zz)
```

But this yields the error message:

```
Error in writeBin(my.array, zz, size = 8) : can only write vector objects
```

I figured that if I flatten the array to a vector as in

```
writeBin (as.vector(my.array),zz, size = 8 )
```

writeBin runs without error message and I am able to read the file to FORTRAN (see [How to write .bin file in R and open it in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101875/how-to-write-bin-file-in-r-and-open-it-in-fortran))

However, I am interested in preserving the structure of the object as I will be working with huge arrays.

Is there anyway to write to .bin in R preserving the object structure?

Answer (score 0):

Binary data does not have "structure".  If you want the structure of the object to be in the binary data, you need to add something manually. For example, you could add some data at the beginning of the file.

The first number would be the number of dimensions, D. Then the next D numbers will be size of each dimension. The remaining bytes are the data.

So, your example would look something like:

```
writeBin(c(length(dim(my.array)), dim(my.array), my.array), raw(), size = 8)
  [1] 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03
 [26] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00
 [51] 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 00 00
 [76] 00 00 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 00 00 00
[101] 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00 00
[126] 00 00 00 0d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0f 00 00 00 00 00
[151] 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 12 00 00 00 00 00 00
[176] 00 13 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[201] 16 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 17 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 19
[226] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1c 00
[251] 00 00 00 00 00 00 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1f 00 00
[276] 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 21 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 22 00 00 00
[301] 00 00 00 00 23 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

In your Fortran code, you would read the first number to find the total number of dimensions, D. Then you would read the next D numbers to find the size or each dimension.  Now you can allocate the structure in Fortran and read the remaining data to fill in all the elements.

Comment: I understand binary data is unformatted. But as I understand your suggestion that still requires to flatten the array before I write it to a .bin in R?

Comment: Yes, you must convert it to a vector first. Otherwise you receive an error, "can only write vector objects".